# How to convert h2o model performance metrics to json in python

Tags: h2o

for example i have this code:

```
import h2o
h2o.init()
from h2o.estimators.naive_bayes import H2ONaiveBayesEstimator
data = h2o.import_file("myfile.csv")
train,valid = data.split_frame([0.8])
predictors = ['col1','col2','col3','col4']
result = 'col_result'
model = H2ONaiveBayesEstimator()
model.train(predictors,result,training_frame=train,validation_frame=valid)
model.model_performance()
```

After the **model.model_performance()**, i will able to see our model performance, but now i want to send over API as JSON data, is there any way i can do the converting in easy way? Thank you.

Comment: Please use a publicly available dataset in `h2o.import_file()` so that this example is reproducible.

Comment: can give me some reference where is the public dataset?

Comment: You can use *any* public dataset of your choosing, for example, `train = h2o.import_file("https://s3.amazonaws.com/erin-data/higgs/higgs_train_10k.csv")`. The code needs to be reproducible, as specified in the Stack Overflow guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, after some research and try and error, i try to see what are the data contained within the result. From this:

```
model.model_performance()
```

It will just show you the model performance right away in console, but if you try to run it as

```
type(model.model_performance())
```

you will get the type of the object returned as:

```
<class 'h2o.model.metrics_base.H2OMultinomialModelMetrics'>
```

which means that the object itself is a class of metcis and according to http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/metrics.html, H2OMultinomialModelMetrics is an instance of MetricBase and if we see in http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/metrics.html#h2o.model.metrics_base.MetricsBase, we found out some of common metrics measurement available.

Further step, if we try to use

```
dir(model.model_performance())
```

We will get a list of properties as expected, consisting of **auc**, **aic**, **rmse**, and so on.

If we try to call:

```
model.model_performance().rmse()
```

In my case, i get 0.4824827476199047.

The most interesting discovery that i get is that when i try to execute **auc** method

```
model.model_performance().auc()
```

i got an error saying that **"AUC"** key doesn't exists in the dictionary

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Development\python\lib\site-packages\h2o\model\model_base.py", line 634, in auc
    for k, v in viewitems(tm): m[k] = None if v is None else v.auc()
  File "D:\Development\python\lib\site-packages\h2o\model\metrics_base.py", line 156, in auc
    return self._metric_json['AUC']
KeyError: 'AUC'
```

and as we can see, it has **_metric_json** dictionary. I try to print the **model.model_performance()._metric_json** dictionary, and i get the dictionary listing all the metric, you can try to use **_metric_json.keys()** to get all the keys and parse it to JSON on your own too.

## **Edit 1**

Even to make life easier, this code show how to even easily convert the class to json string:

```
json_string = str(model.model_performance()._get_metrics)
```

## Edit 2

The string in edit 1 is not json formatted, better do this way to convert to json and dictionary while striping the classes:

```
import json

json_string = json.dumps(str(model.model_performance()._get_metrics),ensure_ascii=False)
python_dictionary = json.loads(json_string)
```

Comment: `type object 'H2ORegressionModelMetrics' has no attribute '_get_metrics'`

Comment: try this `_metric_json`

Answer (score 0):

The H2O python package actually talks to the H2O back-end using a REST API with JSON.  The best way to learn what that looks like is to turn on logging and watch a "conversation" between the Python client front-end and the H2O Java back-end.

Turn on logging with this method call:

```
h2o.start_logging()
```

and take a look at the output.

Here is a pointer to the REST API reference:

- http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/rest-api-reference.html

Comment: I dont want to fire another API request to the JVM runner just to get the detail data for the model performance that i already make. I found the answer anyway